# Get unique item from scope array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with JSON objects in my $scope.users which is working correctly. I'm now trying to set up a "detail" page for an individual user by filtering the users list to get a single user.

I've been close for an excruciating amount of time, and for some reason I can't find documentation or any examples of how to do what I'm doing. Maybe this isn't the correct way to do this in Angular and/or maybe I'm not searching for the right thing?

I've tried getting the object based on userId from the list in the controller, and I've tried passing a resolve in the state, but I didn't get either method to work. What is the best way to go about getting the single user with id of $stateparams.userId?

Everything else is working correctly (i.e. all the routing, getting the users on #/users).

```
// routing section of app.js
// Routing
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'static/partials/main/home.html'
    })
    .state('users', {
      url: '/users',
      templateUrl: 'static/partials/accounts/users.html',
      controller: 'UserController'
    })
    .state('profile', {
      url: '/users/{userId}',
      templateUrl: 'static/partials/accounts/profile.html',
      controller: 'UserController'
    });


// controller.js
var rlGlobalControllers = angular.module('rlGlobalApp.controllers', []);

rlGlobalControllers.controller('UserController', function($scope, $stateParams, $filter) {
  var userId = $stateParams.userId;

  $scope.users = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Shadrack'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'JP'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'Adam'
    }
  ];

  // $scope.user = ??? 
});

# profile.html
<div ng-include src="'/static/partials/shared/header.html'"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>users data: {{ users }}</p>
    <p>user data: {{ user }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: stateParams provides {userId} so you can use them.

Comment: you can use [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to find objects satisfying criteria:

```
$scope.user = $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.id === userId;
})[0];
```

This is the most natural way to solve it. If however your `users` array is very large (like millions, for example (hope it's not)) then for-loop-break solution of juunas is preffered as more effective.

Comment: This is my fravorite answer, and I've tried solutions like this. With this code, I'm not able to see the user scope in the template, however I'm able to see the users scope object. I've updated my question to show the template - any idea why the user scope object is not being seen in the template?

Comment: Also, I've added `console.log(user.id + ' = ' + userId);` before the return to verify the values are there, and they are. There's one pair that matches, but I'm not seeing anything in my $scope.user

Comment: It worked with the equality operator instead of identity. I changed to `return user.id == userId;` and it worked.

Comment: Oh, I see, I guess then that userId is a string and id properties in objects are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this in the controller:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++){
  if($scope.users[i].id === userId){
    $scope.user = $scope.users[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = [],
            keys = [];
          Array_Value.forEach(function (item) {
            var key = item["Field name"];
            if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
            }
          });
          this.Title = output;
```

Instead of Array_value and field name, give your data.